# TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer): Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I'm trying to connect a frontend react app with a rails api backend and I'm having this error

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 36844ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 31928)    TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer):    app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:9:in `[]' app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:9:in `create'
```

The api server is on localhost:3001 and the react app on localhost:3000

This is my registrations controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        newUser = User.create!(
            first_name: params["newUser"]["first_name"],
            last_name: params["newUser"]["last_name"],
            email: params["newUser"]["email"],
            password: params["newUser"]["password"],
            password_confirmation: ["newUser"]["password_confirmation"],
            role: ["newUser"]["role"]
        )
        byebug
        # Usuario creado
        if newUser
            render json: {
                status: :created,
                newUser: newUser
            }
        else
            render json: {
                status: 500
            }
        end
    end
end
```

And this is my react component that makes the post request to the backend:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class Registration extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      first_name: "",
      last_name: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
      password_confirmation: "",
      errors: "",
      role: "user"
    };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
    axios
      .post(
        "http://localhost:3001/registrations",
        {
          newUser: {
            first_name: this.state.first_name,
            last_name: this.state.last_name,
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password,
            password_confirmation: this.state.password_confirmation,
            role: this.state.role
          }
        },
        { withCredentials: true }
      )
      .then(res => console.log("Registro exitoso", res))
      .catch(err => console.log("Error en el registrio", err));
  }

  handleChange(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      [evt.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
    console.log("On change");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="first_name"
            placeholder="Nombre"
            value={this.state.first_name}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            name="last_name"
            placeholder="apellido"
            value={this.state.last_name}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <input
            type="email"
            name="email"
            placeholder="usuario@dominio.com"
            value={this.state.email}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <input
            type="password"
            name="password"
            placeholder="Contraseña"
            value={this.state.password}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <input
            type="password"
            name="password_confirmation"
            placeholder="Confirmar contraseña"
            value={this.state.password_confirmation}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <select name="role" value={this.state.role} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <option value="user">Usuario</option>
            <option value="admin">Administrador</option>
          </select>
          <button type="submit">Registrar!</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Registration;
```

Why am i having this error? I checked types of the variables inside the newUser object both from byebug and debugger. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
password_confirmation: ["newUser"]["password_confirmation"],
```

...should be:

```
password_confirmation: params["newUser"]["password_confirmation"],
```

And this:

```
role: ["newUser"]["role"]
```

...should be:

```
role: params["newUser"]["role"]
```